# Run airflow on schedule that can't be specified with cron

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a number of jobs that are currently being scheduled with multiple cron schedules.

For example, I have a job that runs on:
`35 9,13,16 * * mon-fri` & `40 16 * * mon-fri`

I would like to have 1 dag with the schedule, run at 9:35, 13:35, 16:35, 16:40 mon-fri.
Is it possible to do this with airflow/cron?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with custom timetables https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html

Comment: Thanks, I did try to implement this but I am getting some errors. When I try to update a task to mark as success/fail for a task that is in a dag that runs on a custom timetable, the webserver seems to enter an endless loop of trying to calculate the dag interval. Any idea on why this would be happening? Thanks